# Problems with changing mac address of pi 2

Tags: raspbian

Wanted to change the mac address of eth0 of my Pi.

a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
with Raspbian 
I used

```
macchanger -r eth0
```

and the result was

```
Current MAC:   b8:27:eb:bc:d5:fd (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
Permanent MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Xerox Corporation)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy
```

even tried adding

```
smsc95xx.macaddr=00:00:00:00:00:00
```

to `/boot/cmdline.txt` and

```
#! /bin/sh
ifconfig eth0 down hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
ifconfig eth0 up
```

script file in `/etc/init.d/`, made it executable and did this

```
update-rc.d mac.sh defaults
```

still mac id didn't change

Answer (score 1):

First of all did you forget `sudo` ? It should be `sudo macchanger -r eth0`.
If that doesn't work you may need to try disable the network manager

```
sudo systemctl stop
```

After the stop retry

```
sudo macchanger -r eth0
```

And last

```
sudo systemctl start
```

To start the network manager again.
Hope I did help

Kind regards Michielvk